# Convert a dataframes series with values separated by semicolon to a "1 to 1" dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I didn't really know how to ask this but here's thing. I have a dataframe that contains several columns in the following way:

| Object | Propertiy |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Red;Round;yummy |
| Banana | Yellow,Large,yummy |

And I want a DataFrame in the following way:

| Object | Property |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Red |
| Apple | Round |
| Apple | Yummy |
| Banana | Yellow |
| Banana | Large |
| Banana | Yummy |

Could you help me figuring this out? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

(1) split by regex (comma, or semicolon `;|,`) to get `list` in column

(2) explode lists from the column

```py
df["PROPERTIY"] = df["PROPERTIY"].str.split(";|,")

df = df.explode("PROPERTIY").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Outputs:

```py
   OBJECT PROPERTIY
0   Apple       Red
1   Apple     Round
2   Apple     yummy
3  Banana    Yellow
4  Banana     Large
5  Banana     yummy
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Best

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`, you can use `explode`

```
df.explode('property')
```